# Access invocation URL in Swagger UI

Tags: javascript, dom, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

In a custom JavaScript file in Swagger-UI I was trying to access the request URL  because I needed to add it to a header before I submit the request.

After looking at the source for swagger UI, I've not been able to figure out how to access the request URL.

In a my custom JavaScript file I've cheated by stealing from the DOM using:

```
(function() {
    $(function() {

        $(".submit").click(function (e) {

            // doesn't work
            // log(SwaggerUi.Views.OperationView.invocationUrl);

            var url = $($(this).parentsUntil(".operations")[3]).find(".path")[0].innerText;
            log("URL: " + url);

        });
    });
})();
```

But being this is a hack, it will not work if the route had a parameter like so: `url/{param}`. To find the input param and replace would be another step I would rather not take.

Am I missing some easy way that would allow me to access the request URL something along the lines of: `SwaggerUi.requestUrl`

Comment: what do you mean by invocationUrl?

Comment: The request url for the controller. For example if I have a controller at `/get-items/{itemGuid}`, but the request url is `http://somedomain.com/api/v1/get-items/1234`

Comment: Asking of curiosity, why do you need to invoke the URL from the custom JavaScript?

Comment: I'm looking for the request URL because I need to pass it in the header to my service. Editing the question to reflect request URL instead of invocation URL.

Comment: You are using asp.net web API right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Swashbuckle 5.4 and asp.net web API.

Comment: Still I don't understand why you need the URL in header

Comment: I can't answer your question directly and I'm not sure how that would help you out. 

It is sufficient for this question that I need to have access to the request URL and insert that information into a header before the submit is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devised solution to traverse the DOM to get the information needed instead of using the information being stored by Swagger-UI.

(note: using the embedded Swagger-UI given by Swashbuckle 5.4 your mileage may vary if you use a different version of Swagger-UI)

```js
$(".submit").click(function (e) {

    var originalUrl = $($(this).parentsUntil(".operations")[3]).find(".path")[0].innerText;
    log(originalUrl);

    var outputUrl = "";

    $($(this).parentsUntil(".operations")[3])
        .find("tbody.operation-params tr:contains('path')")
        .find("input")
        .each(function () {

        var pathParam = $(this).attr('name');
        log(pathParam);

        var userInput = $(this).val();
        log(userInput);

        outputUrl = originalUrl.replace("{" + pathParam + "}", userInput);
        log(outputUrl);
    });

    // final requestUrl or invocationUrl
    var requestUrl = $(".footer h4").html().match(/: (\/[\w-]+)/)[1] + outputUrl;
});
```